# Advanced Custom Fields: Display As Bullet Points

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, elementor

I have a custom checkbox field created in Wordpress where the user can select various facilities available at a listed property.

I am building a page template using Elementor.

When I import the data from ACF, it displays as a comma separated list.

Is there any way I can instead get this to display as as a bulleted list?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code to get the output data from ACF as a bulleted list -

```
<?php
    $arr = get_the_field('field_name');
    $str = explode (",", $arr);
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($str as $s){
        echo '<li>'.$s.'</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
?>
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: That's perfect, but how am I able to run this on my page using elementor? I've tried to turn it into a shortcode but it doesn't seem to work :/

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a plugin that let's you create php code snippets and run them with a shortcode such as this: https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/insert-php/

Once you created the php snippet you could try to run it with a shortcode using Elementor's shortcode widget.

Answer (score 0):

I'd slightly adjust Tahmid's excellent answer. In order to allow for empty lines (without a bullet) use this in you `functions.php` file:

```php
/**
 * create a ACF text field with bullets
 * Empty lines stay empty
 * @param string $field_name Name of the field to bullet
 */
function acf_bullets(string $field_name): void {
    $format_acf_bullet = function(
        string $value,
        int $post_id,
        array $form ):string {
        if( empty($value) ) {
            return '';
        }
        $lines = explode( "\n", $value );
        $result = "<ul class=\"theme-ul\">\n";
        foreach( $lines as $line) {
            if( strlen($line)<=1 ) { // empty line, start a new list
                $result .= "</ul><p/><ul class=\"theme-ul\">\n";
            } else {
                $result .= "<li>".$line."</li>\n";
            }
        }
        $result .= "</ul>\n";
        return $result;
    };
    add_filter("acf/format_value/name=$field_name", $format_acf_bullet, 10, 3);
}
```

Call this with `acf_bullets('your-fieldname-here');`

## Explanation

- Add a filter calling `$format_acf_bulltets` for the specific field that:
- Skips complete empty sections
- create an array for all the lines
- open a new  list
- for all entries
- if the line is empty start a new `<ul>` list
- if not wrap the line in `<li></li>`
- close the `<ul>`

The complete list content is appended in string variable `$result` and returned at the end. As exercise make the class name `theme-ul` a parameter for `acf_bullets`